# past perfect in a direct quoted sentence

Tags: past-tense

Quote:

We got off, paid our fare, and the trap rattled back on its way to Leatherhead.

“I thought it as well,” said Holmes as we climbed the stile, “that this fellow should think we had come here as architects, or on some definite business. It may stop his gossip. Good-afternoon, Miss Stoner. You see that we have been as good as our word.”

Question:

Does the past perfect tense "we had come here as..." imply that Holmes wanted to have let the trap driver think that they had come to this village before as architects or on some other business?

But from the context apparently the driver found that Holmes and Waston were not familiar with that area and pointed out a shortcut for them.

If the past perfect tense means Holmes wanted to let the trap driver believe that this time they came as architects or on some other business，why he didn't just use past tense (we came here as) instead?

Comment: No; it's just positioning 'had come' before Holmes' misdirection, which is obviously the case. 100+ years ago, writers were probably more punctilious than now about such things. 'Simple past came' _would_ probably more likely now.

Comment: (Oddly, the passage also contains a non-parallel construction that irks me today: "**We** got off, [we] paid our fare, and [we?] the trap rattled...")

Comment: I may be overthinking this one, but it seems to me at least *part* of the "justification" for Past Perfect *...that we **had come** as architects* stems from the fact that *this isn't true; it's a reference to an "irrealis" unreal counterfactual*.  If they really *were* there as architects, and Holmes thought it best that the fellow should be made aware of this, I might be much happier with Simple Past: *...that this fellow should **know** we **came** here as architects*. Because the Perfect form naturally implies *further away from now* = *further away from **reality***.

Comment: It seems normal to me to say 'we have come here' when they are there. It certainly doesn't mean 'we have been here before'.

Comment: @AndyBonner -  “We got off, paid the fare, and [then] the trap rattled back …”